# Intraday Data Frequency for Bid and Ask Prices vs Trade Prices

Tags: market-data, bloomberg, intraday

When performing the following BDH query for a particular stock:

=BDH("AT0000652011 ISIN","LAST_PRICE","1/3/2023 0:00:00AM","1/9/2023 0:00:00AM","BarTp=B","BarSz=30") for the bid price at 30mins frequency vs

=BDH("AT0000652011 ISIN","LAST_PRICE","1/3/2023 0:00:00AM","1/9/2023 0:00:00AM","BarTp=T","BarSz=30") for the trade price at 30mins frequency,

I get data at various times for the bid or ask price but not for the trade price. For example, when I ran BDH for this stock, each day the trade price is listed only from 1600 to 0030 in 30 minutes interval, but the bid and ask prices are quoted almost the whole day.

My question is - why does the bid or ask price get quoted at (almost all) intraday times where the trade price doesn't?

Comment: Bid ,/ask is a quoted price. Traded prices require actual trades.Trading Hours should be 08:55 - 17:35 Vienna time. Your BDH formula will follow your TZDF time zone settings.

Comment: Thanks @AKdemy. The time zone settings explanation helped. I don't quite understand the bid-ask explanation though, are you saying that it is reasonable for bid-ask prices to be quoted for the whole day? (meaning there are quotes before 08:55 and after 17:35 in your case)

Comment: Exchanges generally don't flush the order book after the close, and any orders with time limits longer than the day will stay there until the next day - so you will still have a bid&ask between the close on one day and the open the next day (plus the order book opens before the actual open to allow users to place orders for the opening auction).